# Gson.toJson throws NullPointerException when the file size > 1GB

Tags: java, json, string, nullpointerexception, gson

I tried to write into Json format in Java, but encountered NullPointerException when the file size is >1GB. Can anyone helps me to fix this issue?

The code keeps generating Json files, and the size of the files keep increasing. Once the file size > 1GB, the code throws exception as shown below. I used different data set for testing, so I don't think it is the data issue. My guess is that there is a size limit for Gson.toJson in Java.

**My code is:**

```
private HashMap<String,HashSet<Token>> tokenCounter = new HashMap<String,HashSet<Token>>();

....

private void writeToFile(){
  try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
    out.println(gson.toJson(tokenCounter));
    out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

**The exception it throws is:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:301)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:790)
    at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:204)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:481)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:460)
    at com.ebay.classification.discovery.DailyDiscovery.writeToFile(DailyDiscovery.java:181)
    at com.ebay.classification.discovery.DailyDiscovery.run(DailyDiscovery.java:169)
    at com.ebay.classification.discovery.TestDailyDiscoveryContinue.run(TestDailyDiscoveryContinue.java:142)
    at com.ebay.classification.discovery.TestDailyDiscoveryContinue.main(TestDailyDiscoveryContinue.java:245)
```

Comment: Strange, the stacktrace indicates the `char[]` passed from [`StringBuffer.toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.toString%28%29) is `null`...

Comment: Yes, I felt kind of strange too. I tried several different data set, and the same exception comes out right at the 1GB point:

Comment: @jlordo That seems impossible though, since array creation takes an `int` argument. `int`s can overflow, but that would throw a `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Comment: The last json.length() before the exception is 1073099184, about half of Integer.MAX_VALUE. The increase in file size is NOT exponential.

Comment: What distribution / version of Java are you using?  Your stack traces don't make sense for Java 7.  (They seem to say that the private `value` field is `null`, and I don't see how that can happen.)

Comment: @StephenC it is Java 6

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.  The line number for 'ensureCapacity' in Java 6 is 152 ... but your stacktrace shows 335.  Precisely what distro are you using?

Comment: java6-ibm-sr5ifx-2009-09-18-windows_64; java.runtime.version = jvmwa6460sr5-20090519_35743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted as an answer to get around formatting issues in comments.

An array of 2^30 char would be 2^31 bytes. As a single string, this is huge! The obvious question that needs to be asked is why you have the code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
out.println(gson.toJson(tokenCounter));
out.close();
```

This can easily be written as:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFileName);
gson.toJson(tokenCounter, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

This would have no significant memory impact, and would be much faster.

This does not answer the question why you get the NPE in a large StringWriter, but, frankly, what you are doing is absurd....

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem! But a new problem appears: I used BufferedReader to read the file, and again, it throws java.lang.NullPointerException:at java.lang.StringBuffer.ensureCapacityImpl(StringBuffer.java:335)
 at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:111)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:309)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:373)

Comment: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
   String line = ""
   while((line = in.readLine()) != null)...

Comment: @Long - My guess is that you have similar absurdity to your original problem; e.g. you are trying to load the file into a String and parse the string rather than parsing directly from the input stream.  Basically Java strings and string buffers cannot contain more than MAX_INT characters.  Buffering your file contents in a huge String doesn't scale ... and is just not sensible.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the advise. I just get this code from someone else. Will try to rewrite the code to have data stored in a more reasonable format.